# What is the difference between these sentences? Which sentence is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-simple

What is the difference between this sentences?:

> 1) "Where do your parents live?"
>
> 2) "Where is your parents live?"

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 is correct. Sentence 2 is incorrect.

Sentence 2 is incorrect for 2 reasons. First, "your parents" is a plural noun, so `is` is the incorrect version of the verb `to be`. You should use `are` here.

Second, we use the word `do` when asking about 'how' or 'where' or 'when' objects perform their action.

For instance, the sentence

> Your parents do live in London

becomes the question

> Where do your parents live?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct, the second one isn't, it is not grammatical. You could say:

> Where are your parents living?

if the parents are temporarily living somewhere. If they have been living somewhere for a while and they will continue to live there in the future, use:

> Where do your parents live?

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1 is OK, sentence 2 needs a correction like this:

> Where is your parents' *home*?